# Static dropdown using AJAX,PHP

Tags: php, ajax

singleselect.html

```
<html>
  <script>
    function singleselect(str)
    {
      var xmlhttp;
      if(str.length == 0)
      {
        document.getElementById("sing").innerHTML="";
        return;
      }

      if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        
      }
      else
      {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      xmlhtttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          document.getElementById("sing").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responsetext;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("POST","singleselect.php?s=" +str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
  </script>

  <style>
   div { font-family:verdana; font-size:13px; margin-left:400px; margin-top:100px; }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div>
     Select a country : 
       <select onchange="document(this.value)">
        <option>Select a country</option>
        <option value="0">INDIA</option>
        <option value="1">United States of America</option>
        <option value="2">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="3">Australia</option>
     </select>
    </div>

    <div id="sing"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

singleselect.php

```
<?php    

$store[0] = "Please select a country";
$store[1] = "Andhra Pradesh";
$store[2] = "New York";
$store[3] = "London";
$store[4] = "Austraila";

$s = $_REQUEST['s'];

?>
```

When I click on a country, a list of states related to a country should be displayed and i want to be done static in php but using database. Since I am jQuery and AJAX. I need your guidance.

Comment: what do you mean static? If you are sennding values from selectbox you will need <option value="x">. Then in the php file just connect o db and query the db for the desired value and echo the result in the desired manner.

Comment: But i want to use static content instead of using from database

Comment: You wrote "and i want to be done static in php but using database" so you got me confused. Well then you will have to have this list of countries in text file or csv or whatever and format it in the way so that you can read it easily. For example if you use text file maybe you can format it like this Country:City; then read the file explode() it so that you get array and search for needed values. Search the web for reading txt files and explode() function

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion, but can we do using PHP arrays instead of an text file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data for the cities in arrauy maybe you can do something like this:

```
$store[0] = "Please select a country";
$store[1][0] = "Andhra Pradesh";
$store[2][0] = "New York";
$store[3][0] = "London";
$store[4][0] = "Austraila";
$c= $_POST['s'];
if(isset($store[$c]) && is_array($store[$c])){
    foreach($store[$c] as $k=>$v){
        echo $v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want with your states. Also it would be better to use country codes instead of numeric indexes.

```
// states.php 

$states = array (
'IN' => array (
    'indian state',
    'indian state 2'            
    ),
'US' => array (
    'US state',
    'US state 2'
    )
);

$select = '';
if(isset($_POST['s']) && isset($states[$_POST['s']])) {
$select .= '<select name="states">';
foreach($states[$_POST['s']] as $state) {
        $select .= '<option value="' . $state . '">' . $state  . '</option>'; 
}
$select .= '</select>';     
echo $select;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want, but what I understand is you want a state drop down list according to country. So you need to do it in `singleselect.php`

```
$state_list = array(
'0' =>  array(
    'state 1',
    'state 2',
    'state 3'
    ),
'1' =>  array(
    'state 4',
    'state 5',
    'state 6'
    ),
'2' =>  array(
    'state 7',
    'state 8',
    'state 9'
    )
);

$select = '<select name="state">';
foreach($state_list[$_REQUEST['s']] as $key => $value) 
{
    $select .= '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
$select .= '</select>';

echo $select;
```

Maybe it will help you.